# any problems with UseLogin yes? /(workaround on no system information safe?)

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, security, login

this is about the system information, shown to the user after login on an ubuntu-server.

by default, an ubuntu-server is showing you system information, when logging in, such as the servers ip-address, the number of running processes, number of users logged in, etc. i think that message is really cool and helpfull.
after playing around and testing, it is not shown anymore.

i tried to make some research, but one problem with that is, that most people, who talk about this subject, mix two things up: this system information and the message of the day(motd).

but the **motd** **and** the **system information** are definetly **not the same thing**. i have seen both showing, the system information and after that the message of the day.

**when did it stopped beeing shown?**

following  [this guide](https://www.howtoforge.com/set-up-ssh-with-public-key-authentication-debian-etch), 
to allow only logins with public keys, this is what i changed:

- in /etc/ssh/sshd_config i replaced `#PasswordAuthentication yes` with  `PasswordAuthentication no` 
  and i replaced `UsePAM yes` with `UsePAM no`

now, when doing login via ssh only the message of the day was shown. logging in on the actual/physical server on tty1(i mean without remote access), it still shows both messages.

**how i got it back again...**

i tested some options.

after setting `UseLogin yes` it showed me both again.

in ancient times (2000) i found out, [there have been problems with this option](http://www.securiteam.com/unixfocus/5MQ070A1QU.html), but this should not be an issue anymore, right?

actually, i dont really understand why pam is beeing disabled in that tutorial, becouse it is about deactivating password login in the first place. but anyways, turning that option to `UsePAM yes` also does net help me with my problem.

now, **the actual question** is. am i safe with these settings in /etc/ssh/sshd_config :

`UseLogin yes`,
`PasswordAuthentication no`
`UsePAM no`

?

**edit** **1**
i must have mixed up something(beeing confused, playing around with too many settings) before when i said "Use PAM yes" again, doesent solve the problem.

when i only set `PasswordAuthentication no` the system information continue beeing shown when you login.

Comment: UseLogin causes you to use the login(1) process for interactive login over SSH, which is probably not what you want. You would be better placed fixing the root-cause of your problem, which will be a PAM misconfiguration. The system information comes from PAM, so check what you did to your `/etc/pam.d/sshd` configuration. [More details](https://askubuntu.com/questions/7949/where-does-the-system-information-information-come-from-on-login).

Comment: thank you Cosmic Ossifrage! "UsePAM no" might have been the misconfiguration. :-)  i just setted up a clean new instalation to be really shure, what i changed, this time only setting "PasswordAuthentication no", and it works fine. so in contrary to what some tutorials say, "UsePAM no" does not improve my security?